# How to show suggestions words from list of words?

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, cpu-word

I've list of words, when the user enter characters I need to show some suggestions for him.
How can I perform that using typeScript?
Taking care of performance wise!

Comment: What do you have so far? Where are you stuck at? Provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think What you are looking for auto-complete.
If you are using Angular Material you can check out `mat-autocomplete`

see this stackblitz for a live example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-autocomplete

And here is the official documentations:
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview